# TypeError: model() missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, arguments, odeint

I have these three ODE to solve. Here's the code I'm using.

When I compile, I get the following error message:

TypeError: model() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'T' and 't'

I don't know what is happening since T and t are mentioned in the model function.

Can anybody help me with this?

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


v0 = 10.0 #L/min, vazão volumétrica de entrada (CSTR)
V = 100.0 #L, volume do reator (CSTR)
k = 0.14*10**(-5) #L/mol.min, constante de velocidade da reação (aprox: independente da temperatura)
Na0 = 500.0 #mol, concentração de A na entrada do reator (CSTR)
DeltaH_r = -5.9*10**(-5) #cal/mol
CpA = 40.0 #cal/mol.K
CpB = 18.0 #cal/mol.K
Tent = 50.0+273.15 #K, temperatura na entrada no reator

def model(Na, Nb, T, t):
    dNadt = (Na0 / V) * v0 - (Na / V) * v0 + (- k * (Na / V)**2) * V
    dNbdt = -(Nb / V) * v0 + 0.5 * (k * (Na / V)**2) * V
    dTempdt = ((-DeltaH_r) * (- k * (Na / V) * V) - Cp_A * V * v0 * (T - Tent)) / (Na * CpA + Nb *CpB)
    return [dNadt, dNbdt, dTempdt]


t = np.linspace(0,20)

Chutes = [500.0, 0.1, 300.0] #Chute inicial


Y = odeint(model, Chutes, t)
```

Comment: it seems `odeint` expects `def model(Na, Nb):` without `T`, `t`

Answer (score 0):

I never used it but I checked example in documentation for [scipy.integrate.odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) and I think you have to add `args=(val1, val2)` with values which will be assigned to `T` and `t`

```
Y = odeint(model, Chutes, t, args=(val1, val2))
```

so finally it will use `model` with

```
Na = Chutes
Nb = t
T = val1
t = val2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In fact, t is the time points sequence to solve for model, and T is an input variable to integrate with respect to t. So I think they cannot be set as args.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer.

I am not sure why, but when I "concatenated" Na, Nb and T in one single vector (I called it z), it worked.

```py
def model(z, t):
    Na, Nb, T = z
    dNadt = (Na0 / V) * v0 - (z[0] / V) * v0 + (- k * (z[0] / V)) * V
    dNbdt = (-z[1] / V) * v0 + 0.5 * (k * (z[0] / V)) * V
    dTdt = ((-DeltaH_r) * (-k * (z[0] / V)) * V - CpA * (z[0] / V) * v0 * (z[2] - Tent)) / (z[0] * CpA + z[1] * CpB)
    return [dNadt,dNbdt,dTdt]
```